# Поиск хэштега в тексте по паттерну

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, в нем слова с хэштегами. Я бы хотел найти слова с хэштегами. Написал функцию, которая принимает на вход текст и выдает строчку с найдеными хэштегами:

```
def hashtag(text):
    res = re.findall('#.+', text)
    return res
```

Но есть проблема, если мне на вход придет текст, где слово в хэштеге будет не в конце, то эта функция не поймает слово, а выдаст кусок текста целиком.

Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [51]: s = "blah-blah, #tag1 blah-blah, #tag2, blah-blah"

In [52]: tags = re.findall(r'(#\w+)', s)

In [53]: tags
Out[53]: ['#tag1', '#tag2']
```

Comment: Черт, ну конечно же!!! Большое спасибо

Comment: @CerebroSpinal, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа [отметьте ответ как решение и/или проголосуйте за ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Comment: сделал. Спасибо за подсказку :)